# ¿Cómo puedo hacer para con el mismo evento de hover de la tarjeta, modificar también el span y el i?

Tags: html, css

Hola gente de Stack Overflow, esta es mi primer pregunta en el foro.

Actualmente estoy trabajando en un diseño para una página web pero tengo un problema para crear un efecto.

[image]

Tengo este tipo de tarjetas en mi página web, este es el código HTML y CSS que tengo para crearlas.
HTML:

```
<div class="secondmain__card">
    <i class="fas fa-heartbeat"></i>
    <h3>Cardiología</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab, id.</p>
    <span>Conocer más</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.secondmain__card{
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    width: 250px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    height: 350px;
    color: #000;
    padding: 20px 10px;
    margin-right: 6px;
    transition: 0.3s all ease-out;
}
.secondmain__card i{
    color: #51ACDC;
    font-size: 90px;
    margin-bottom: 35px; 
}
.secondmain__card h3{
    font-size: 27px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.secondmain__card p{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 16px;
}
.secondmain__card span{
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #51ACDC;
    border-radius: 20px;
    color: #FFF;
    padding: 6px 10px;
    margin-top: 30px;
}
```

El problemas que tengo es que estoy añadiendo un selector con pseudoclase hover a la tarjeta en general, de esta manera:

```
.secondmain__card:hover{
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0 4px  #51ACDC;
    background: #51ACDC;
    color: white;
}
```

Pero el efecto que consigo es este:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**¿Cómo puedo hacer para con el mismo evento de hover de la tarjeta, modificar también el span y el i? Saludos**

Comment: Y qué te impide meter más css dentro de ese `.secondmain__card:hover{}` exactamente igual que hiciste dentro del `.secondmain__card{}` sin el hover? De hecho, no necesitas ni andar repitiendo las clases, puedes usar `.secondmain__card:hover{ span {color: red}}` y funcionaría perfectamente. De hecho, es como se suele hacer, en vez de andar repitiendo una y otra vez cada clase, las *anidas*

Comment: @Benito-B Pero que código css meto dentro del hover??

Answer (score 0):

Ok, ya lo pude hacer jeje. Era bastante básico solo que según yo no me había funcionado. Simplemente con `.secondmain__card:hover i{}` puedo modificarlo.

Comment: Bienvenido a [Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/) gracias por ayudar a esta comunidad. pero tu respuesta parece mas bien un comentario, dale un vistazo al siguiente contenido [Cómo responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) un saludo.